# Can not use class in a function as a parameter (JScript)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do a small JavaScript Lab. In the lab, first I created an Animal object :

```
function Animal(species, nature) {

  this.species = species;
  this.nature = nature;

  var preys = new Array();

  Animal.prototype.getSpecies = function() {
      return species;
  }
  Animal.prototype.getNature = function() {
      return nature;
  }
  Animal.prototype.getPreys = function () {
      return preys;
  }

  Animal.prototype.setNature = function (newNature) {
      nature = newNature;
  }
  Animal.prototype.setSpecies = function (newSpecies) {
      species = newSpecies;
  }
  Animal.prototype.setPrey = function (newPreys) {
      preys = newPreys;
  }
}
```

Then, I created a World object which will basically store a number of animal object and separate them according to their nature.

```
/// <reference path="Animal.js" />

function World() {

  var animals = new Array();

  animals.push(new Animal("Wolf", "Carnivore"));
  animals.push(new Animal("Crocodile", "Carnivore"));
  animals.push(new Animal("Sheep", "Omnivore"));

  World.prototype.getOmnivores = function () {
      return animals.filter(getOmnivores());
  }

  function getOmnivores(animal) {
  }
}
```

In my `getOmnivors` function, I can not use the `Animal` class as a variable. It is a little bit complicated for me cause I am new in JavaScript and regardless of their types we are using `var` keyword (Or not using in some places such as parameters in functions).

What did I do wrong and how can I fix it? I could not reach the `Animal` class in my private function `getOmnivores`. I think program does not understand that it is the class called `Animal`

I hope I explained well. Have a nice day!

**EDIT**

Error picture :[image: Error picture :]

Comment: Show how you try to access `Animal` in `function getOmnivores`. What error you get?

Comment: You're using a constructor function *name* as an argument, that's a problem. Why would `getOmnivores` need an argument at all? What would be the implementation?

Comment: @Justinas when I write `animal.` into my `getOmnivors` function, it says **The provided list contains all identifiers in the file**.

Comment: @Jeroen I changed Animal, which is a parameter in `getOmnivores` function, to animal or xxx but nothing changed. And I saw examples on the internet for using `Array.filter()` function. In the examples, there are using like that. Here is the [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: `filter` expects a `Function` but you're passing the *returned value* of `getOmnivores()` (which is probably `undefined` or `Array`). Try this instead: `return animals.filter(getOmnivores);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Animal` is the Class name, you don't need it there. When using `filter` each element of the array is automatically passed on to the callback function as the first parameter of that function.

Since each element of the array is an instance of the class `Animal` you can use it straight away.

Also, the syntax `{ClassName}.Prototype.{functionName}` should not be used within that same Class, because by the time the interpreter reaches that line the Animal Class has not yet been defined. That syntax is used on already existing and defined classes. Use `this.{functionName}` instead.

```
function Animal(species, nature) {

  this.species = species;
  this.nature = nature;
  this.preys = new Array();

  this.getSpecies = function() {
      return this.species;
  }
  this.getNature = function() {
      return this.nature;
  }
  this.getPreys = function () {
      return this.preys;
  }

  this.setNature = function (newNature) {
      this.nature = newNature;
  }
  this.setSpecies = function (newSpecies) {
      this.species = newSpecies;
  }
  this.setPrey = function (newPreys) {
      this.preys = newPreys;
  }
}
function World() {
  var animals = new Array();

  animals.push(new Animal("Wolf", "Carnivore"));
  animals.push(new Animal("Crocodile", "Carnivore"));
  animals.push(new Animal("Sheep", "Omnivore"));

  this.getOmnivores = function () {
    return animals.filter(this.filterOmnivores);
  }

  this.filterOmnivores= function(animal) {
    return animal.getNature()=='Omnivore';
  }
}
myworld = new World();
console.log(myworld.getOmnivores());
```

A working fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/47dyg1q9/

Comment: Thanks a lot, that really helped me, have a nice day !!

Answer (score 1):

The [filter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) takes a function as a paramter.

You must provide the function but in your code you are instantly calling the function:

```
World.prototype.getOmnivores = function () {
  return animals.filter(getOmnivores());
}
```

Remove the parentheses to provide just the function without calling it, or insert an anonymous function:

```
World.prototype.getOmnivores = function () {
  return animals.filter(getOmnivores);
}
// or
World.prototype.getOmnivores = function () {
  return animals.filter(function (animal) {
    return animal.nature === "omnivore";
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot, have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the function as an argument, not what it returns.

```
 return animals.filter(isOmnivore);
```

And `isOmnivore` becomes

```
function isOmnivore(animal) {
  animal.nature == 'Omnivore';
}
```